# I don't understand the following error in my website relaying code that forwards the message from the website to the desired discord channel

Tags: python, discord, forward

I'm having trouble to understand the error with this code. It's all good and no errors whatsoever but when I run it says this:
`

> ```
>     token = discord.utils.oauth_token(client_id, client_secret)
> AttributeError: module 'discord.utils' has no attribute 'oauth_token'
> ```

`
I am using the 'discord' module and using these:

> ```
> from discord.utils import oauth_url
> ```

This is the line(s) where the code has trouble:

> ```
> # use the client ID and client secret to get an OAuth token for your bot
> token = discord.utils.oauth_token(client_id, client_secret)
> ```

Thanks in advance and excuse my problem and writing as I'm new to this website :/

I tried to search if anyone else had a similar problem but can't find and also tried to use the chatGPT but the demand is too high atm and it can't function well at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the function `oauth_url`from`discord.utils`. This means you can call the function directly without specifying the library or module you called it from. So

```
token = oauth_url(client_id, client_secret)
```

will do.